# Can an immigrant get a mortgage in the us?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, law

My dad has been in them U.S for 9 years now and he has been working in the same location. He has been in the U.S before that but he went back to San Salvador the country he has born in. When he came to the U.S the first time he obtain a social security card, and he has no work permit or green card. The bank wont give him a mortgage without a green card, he has the funds to afford a home, what can we do ?

Comment: If he cannot work, how can he afford a home? If he already has enough money for a home, why does he need a mortgage?

Comment: The bank won't give a loan to someone who can get deported in a whim, you do understand that don't you?

Comment: He doesn't need to have a green card, but he does need to have legal immigration status for the bank to feel comfortable giving him a loan.  I was given a mortgage by a major bank when I was just on a non-immigrant visa. So it certainly is possible. The problem here seems to be he has a SSN, but no authority to work.

Answer (score 5):

There are two Questions:

1. May a foreigner own property in the US?- -the answer is yes.
2. May a foreigner obtain financing to pay for property in the US- -the answer again is Yes but with qualifications.

Financial institutions do not care about your nationality, only your ability to pay over time. For long term debt the lender will want assurances that the borrower has the ability and means to pay the debt over time. A legal resident in the US should have no more difficulty obtaining financing than a citizen under similar life circumstances. The Lender is also under legal obligation to confirm that the borrower is who they say they are, will have the ability to pay over time AND have no malicious intent in the purchase.

Persons who do not have legal status in the US, AND who do not have the means to pay for property outright will have difficulty obtaining financing as they will have trouble establishing the requirements of the Lender. This is simple math, a lender will be reluctant to lend to any person who is more likely to have difficulty paying the obligation than another. In your case Your father would be an unlikely candidate for a mortgage because he cannot establish his legal status nor can he guarantee that he will have the legal right to earn a means to pay the loan back. This puts the lender at risk both of losing the money lent AND losing the right to repossess the property if the borrower doesn't pay.

Despite all of the obstacles I have indicated above, it is still possible for your father to purchase property legally, but the risk and the cost go way up for him as a borrower. There may be sellers willing to finance property over time, but your father's status puts him at a disadvantage if the seller is not honest.

There may be community coalitions which can help you work through the challenges of property ownership.

Please see [these](http://www.nydailynews.com/new-york/undocumented-immigrants-buy-property-u-s-article-1.1792789) [related](http://money.usnews.com/money/personal-finance/articles/2014/11/04/buying-real-estate-as-an-immigrant-to-the-us) [articles](http://www.workpermit.com/us/relocation/buying_home.htm)